# How to match windows and linux mouse speed (with acceleration turned ON)

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ubuntu, mouse

I have Ubuntu at work and Windows 7 at my home. Mouse speed on both OSes are very different so I feel very painful to adjust from one to another when I get to office in the morning and get back home in the night.  Both mouses are exactly the same brand and model.  I want to find a way to exactly match the speed on both systems.

All posts or discussions I found on the web are for FPS gamers, to whom precision is more important so they all disable acceleration.  I am not a gamer, so I have acceleration turned on on both OSes so I can have the benefit of acceleration.

For Windows, there are the following settings:

1. In registry HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse\{MouseSpeed,MouseThreshold1,MouseThreshold2}
2. In Control Panel, a slider that controls the speed (I'm not sure if this a separate dimension independent to the above or not).

For Ubuntu, I found these settings:

1. In xinput: AccelerationProfile, ConstantDeceleration, AdaptiveDeceleration;
2. In xset: an acceleration and a threshold;
3. A slider in mouse settings (again, I'm not sure if this is a separate dimension independent to the above or not).

If we see mouse speed as a function of settings and past movements, then my question is how to find a way, given any parameter in windows, find a set of parameters in linux so that
`f_windows(past_movements | windows_settings)` and `f_linux(past_movements | linux_settings)` are as close as possible.

Since linux have more dimensions in setting, I am trying to match windows settings in linux, not the other way around.

Anyone has a better idea on how `f_windows` and `f_linux` look like?  The description on existing docs are so vague and unclear.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Windows 7 laptop? If so you could mimic your desktop settings then bring your laptop to work with you.

Comment: @Insane, no I have to use company provided desktop to work.  I can't use my own laptop to do the work.

Comment: No.. I mean bring your laptop with you then just mimic the sensitivity settings until it feels the same

Comment: @Insane, unfortunately I don't have a windows laptop :-(